# i am using phonegap first time and not able to connect vibration plugins, so how can i connect vibration and more plugins?

Tags: cordova, plugins

How can I connect plugins as I was trying for vibration plugins?

Please help me to add plugins with whole description and please give the deep info about hoe many plugins are available.

Answer (score 0):

You can find full description, installation process and usage. [HERE](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-vibration)